# How to listen on TCP input from other device?

Tags: python, tcp

I'm trying to do my first TCP program in python and not sure how to do what I need to do. I found all the tutorials how to create TCP connections so I have this right now.

```
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 


host = "192.168.0.6"

port = 14150



s.connect((host, port))

msg = s.recv(1024)

s.close()
print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

And I have a Speedway R420[Picture of the output I'm trying to listen to.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw3ER.png)
This is for my thesis and I'm trying to gather the RFID tags and eventually start processing them to MySQL database when I first can read them over python.

Comment: For the server, you need to accept a connection. And in client ( different application ) you need to send a byte array to the server to receive it. Read the following link, it might help you : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm

Comment: Okay thanks! I'm trying to write client that would read those RFID tag messages.